# Logitech T400 Zone Touch Mouse not pairing to unifying receiver

Tags: logitech-mouse

I have this logitech t400 zone touch mouse that seems to be messed up with pairing. The unifying receiver software says to turn the device off, then on again. I do that and it doesn't pick it up at all. When doing this pairing process the mouse works and I can use it to move the cursor around and so on. I think the drivers or something are messed up.

I have no idea how to fix this so i hope you can help me.

Comment: By the way, it has the unifying logo on the mouse.

Comment: Could it be paired with another receiver in your neighborhood while that machine is still powered on?

Comment: No. I live in the middle of nowhere. It's currently 2017 and this problem has still not been resolved. I haven't moved on. I've been trying to fix this for the past 4 years and never gave up, never got a new mouse, and never will stop trying.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce it with a different system?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem few days ago. Luckily I have another Logitech mouse to test. And my test showed that reciever works well,since I easily connected second mouse to it. Then I tried to connect T400 to working reciever and Unifying app detected no mouse around me, so in my case problem is definitely in mouse. Mouse's transmitter seems to be broken...